# Using Laser Fence to Mis-direct Bullets

Tags: warfare

Could a laser fence be projected from the top of a helmet that could misdirect bullets?  The generally downward vector of LASER light on a bullet targeting the chest would cause a photoelectric effect on the upper surface of the bullet proportional to strength of LASER light.  The resulting force vector would be downwards and gently alter the angular momentum.  I believe that this subtle force could create enough instability to significantly alter the bullet's trajectory.  After researching bullet-proofing technologies, there is little overall emphasis on redirecting bullets prior to hitting the target.  This would be a relatively novel approach on defensive technology.

Comment: You do realize what a laser actually is, right? (Hint: If light could deflect bullets, guns wouldn't work in sunlight)

Comment: Light does actually exert a force on things, (otherwise, solar sails would not work.) The required energy is extreme though. A what-if about it: https://what-if.xkcd.com/87/

Comment: Seems like this must not be the right place for this type of question.  Sorry to bother you all.  Best of luck with your forum.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about real lasers, light doesn't really have sufficient mass to redirect such a small object, particularly a fast-moving one before it actually hits you. Sure, light can move objects (see solar sails), but that requires a relatively low mass, large surface area, and a *lot* of light. Which you don't really have here.

The best you could hope for would be that quickly evaporating the metal on one side of the bullet would cause it to be deflected, but even then, that probably wouldn't create enough of a change in direction to cause it to miss.

If you're looking for some kind of bullet deflection field, lasers aren't the right answer.

Comment: Any ideas on what sort of bullet deflection field might be effective?  I'm thinking of something practical and wearable that doesn't impair soldier mobility in the same way that traditional bullet-proof clothing does.

Comment: @Erik Weitzel - Might be easier to just wait for lighter and more effective bulletproofing technologies than kevlar, like the composite metal foam discussed in [this article](http://phys.org/news/2016-04-metal-foam-obliterates-bullets.html).

Comment: Very interesting.  I'm more keen on identifying ways to stop bullets prior to impact on target though.  Very little effort has gone into this possibility.  Tracking would be nearly impossible, but a stable field that creates a force on metal objects would have potential.  I've seen work on inductors creating magnetic force, but that would require immense amounts of energy and only apply to ferrous metals.

Comment: Ferrous metals also have the property that in a sufficiently strong external magnetic field, their internal magnetic domains quickly align with the field, which means the metal is attracted to the source of the field, not repulsed. And in any case bullets move so fast that even a pretty powerful field from a bunch of magnets close to the path of the bullet won't have time to deflect their path very much, check out [this mythbusters segment](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/electromagnetic-watch-minimyth/) (they use the strongest magnets about 3 minutes into it)